# Помогите решить задачу!

Tags: css

http://www.szsi.com.ua/page/page7/index.html ссылка на сайт

Нижнее меню 
 при наведении на картинку, там где «Индивидуальное проектирование» и «Типовые проекты», эти надписи тоже должны подсвечиваться цветом меню, а не оставаться белыми, а он остаються белыми.

```
 ul.menu{
        width: 945px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }
    ul.menu li{
        float: left;

        width: 173px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-right: 20px;
        display: block;
        background: #fff;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 1%;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.menu li.mr{
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    ul.menu li img{
        width: 173px;
        height: 98px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-bottom: -6px;
    }
    ul.menu li a {
        width: 133px;
        display: block;
        padding: 2px 21px 8px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 18px 'PT Sans Narrow', 'Arial Narrow';    
        color: #742F00;
    }
    ul.menu li.mr a{
        padding: 18px 0 13px !important;
        width: 175px;
    }
    ul.menu li.mr1 a{
        padding: 18px 21px 13px !important; 
    }
    ul.menu li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute; top: 150px;
    }
    ul.menu li a:hover{ 
        color: #fff;
        background: #944C09 !important; 
    }
    ul.menu li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
    }
    ul.menu li:hover ul {

        position: absolute; 
        width: 173px;
        background: #E5780E;
    }
    ul.menu li:hover ul li {    
        float: none;    
    }
    ul.menu li:hover ul li a {
        width: 123px;
        background: #E5780E;
        color: #fff;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px 26px;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed #fff;
        text-align: center; 
        float: none !important;
    }
    ul.menu li.mr1:hover ul li a{
        width: 133px;
        padding: 30px 26px 15px 26px;
    }
    ul.menu li.mr:hover ul li a{
        width: 175px;
        padding: 30px 26px 15px 26px;
    }
    ul.menu li ul li a:hover{
        color: #fff;
        background: #944C09;
    }
    ul.menu li:hover ul li.brd a{
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Подскажите как сделать чтобы меню не оставалось белым?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.menu li:hover p a {
    background: #E5780E;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: Из-за того что у вас разные padding'и у ссылок внутри p и ссылок внутри списка второго уровня, я укоротил ответ до изменения только фона.